# Angular directive for editing hidden JSON input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to create an angular directive which I can apply to a hidden input field. Basically, the hidden input contains a JSON string. I want to create some custom controls with JS which modify the value of that hidden input. Can you point me in the right direction?

So far I tried using jQuery to convert the JSON string to an object, and then saved it to the input DOM element using jQuery's .data(). However, I can't see how to access an object's .data() from within Angular. That's why I think a directive might be the best way to go here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would not store the json out to the dom in a `data-` field. Instead I would go down the path you are suggesting with a directive, and keep $scope in the directive to represent the json object. With this approach you don't need to serialize and deserialize json to get access to the objects. Another advantage is that you avoid tight coupling between your dom and your javascript code.

While it still would be possible to integrate Jquery's data in the directive I would discourage it and instead rely on a clean object model managed by the directive.